# How to replace/remove evaluating from array exp?

Tags: java, arrays

I have one array with certains string for evaluated, example:

```
String[] arrayExp = {
    "[BDremux 1080p]",
    "[AC3 5.1 Castellano-DTS 5.1 Ingles+Subs]",
    "[ES-EN]",
    "[MicroHD 1080p]",
    "[AC3 5.1-Castellano-AC3 5.1 Ingles+Subs]",
    "[HDTV 720p]",
    "[AC3 5.1 Español Castellano]"
};
```

And now have one string with similar name with these

```
String name = "Name from movie [BDremux 1080p][AC3 5.1 Castellano-DTS 5.1 Ingles+Subs][ES-EN]";
```

I'm try evaluating from these array and remove, to output string so name

**String name = "Name from movie";**

I do not have very clear how to do it

It is something like a dictionary of words, if the name is erased has

Comment: So, am I right you wish remove from *name* all values, that exists in arrayExp?

Comment: No, that's just a dictionary. What must be changed is: String name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have a certain pattern in which your informations come in you can use Regexp. It makes more sense to look for the actual informations than for stuff which belongs not in the result (It would be an infinite amount of expressions).
So for example if you want to filter out everything in `[..]`  it would look like:

```
    String name = "Name from movie [BDremux 1080p][AC3 5.1 Castellano-DTS 5.1 Ingles+Subs][ES-EN]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

You use a regexp pattern (in this case the pattern is: `\[(.*?)\]`. Java needs to have `\\` for a `\`) which searchs for a [ and capture everything behind it till a ] comes. Next you use a matcher to do the actual work. It searches for the pattern in your input string. In this case the output would be

> [BDremux 1080p]
>
> [AC3 5.1 Castellano-DTS 5.1 Ingles+Subs]
>
> [ES-EN]

Comment: Thank you, from this, I can also evaluate the pattern is equal to the dictionary. Because there are some conditions that do not want to remove